# FFMPEG and MP3. How decode

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, decode

How to decode mp3 audio using ffmpeg (using the API)? If not complicated - example code?

PS I went to open the file, find the audio channels. then I do not understand what to do ...

Answer (score 1):

It's nice to go all the way through the tutorials but this part of the tutorial deals with [decoding audio](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial03.html) (although I am currently having a problem with it as avcodec_decode_audio3() is the updated version of avcodec_decode_audio2()).

Hope it helps,

Infinitifizz